# am using blender 2.82 and using a alpha front and back leaf, but i cannot get it to appear on the back face of my mesh

Tags: uv, node-editor, texture-coordinates

[image: Problem and node setup]

I have pictures with the node set up and key parts. I have followed a few tutorials but the same thing keeps happening...I Have Tried a few Combinations with the geometry node UV map node still no luck and still no luck... i can get you the blend file if you can fix https://drive.google.com/open?id=1iwCDp7h3jex25NXdBdKjoOZtyq6JNhbi thanks in advance

Comment: I checked your file and it works fine for me. I just opened it and didn't modify anything.

Comment: So it Could Be Software Problem??

Comment: Because I watch a couple of tutorials and in the tutorial, they were saying I should enable backfacing but those are older versions of blender...but for some reason it's not working on my blender and its frustrating

Comment: Try to remove the translucent and it's mix shader from the back shader and add a little transmission on the principled shader instead of it.

Comment: I feel so dumb .....That was the problem Thank you so much, it fixed the problem